# How do I answer a call on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

How do I answer a call on the Ubuntu phone? I have tried pressing the answer button (green) and swiping across the screen, and nothing happens.

It is like the touch screen is inactive. The phone otherwise works normally as I can make outgoing calls and receive texts etc. I just cannot seem to answer incoming calls!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roger, it sounds like you know how to answer the call but it's not working for you. This happened me a few times before the update. I'd get a call and be swiping like a mad man but nothing happened... touch screen would work with everything else just not answering calls. This ended when I got the most recent update, maybe this could help you?

Answer (score 3):

you can answer an incoming call by wiping the "button" (the grey rectangle with "< >" on it) to the right side. Or decline the call by wiping the rectangle in the other direction towards the red icon.

Answers this your question?

Best wishes,
Matthias

[image: answer incoming call by wiping the button to the right]

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a call and want to take it, the standard way is to move the white “button" with the 2 arrows from its middle position towards the green phone. If you want to close it, you move it towards the red phone.